# How to process each line of file parrallely in Spark using java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a file which contains multiple urls.
I want to read each of this url and do some processing on it.
As processing part is independent for each url I would like to do this in parallel on Spark.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> textFile = context.textFile("urlFile");
/* Now for each line of this textFile I need to call below */

ExtractTrainingData ed = new ExtractTrainingData();
List<Elements> list = ed.getElementList(inputUrl);
ed.processElementList( inputUrl, list);
```

Can any one suggest how can I do this?

Comment: What kind of processing are you wanting to do on the text file? I am guessing make http requests with the urls? Are you wanting the results from the request in one rdd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each URL is in other line, then you can do foreach:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> textFile = context.textFile("urlFile");

textFile.foreach (new VoidFunction<String>() {
    public void call (String line) {
        // this code will be executed parallely for each line in file
        ExtractTrainingData ed = new ExtractTrainingData();
        List<Elements> list = ed.getElementList(inputUrl);
        ed.processElementList( inputUrl, list); 
    }
});
```

If result list also should be parallelized, then:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.sparkexample.WordCount").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> textFile = context.textFile("urlFile");

textFile.map (new Function<String, List<Elements>() {
    public List<Elements> call (String line) {
        // this code will be executed parallely for each line in file
        ExtractTrainingData ed = new ExtractTrainingData();
        List<Elements> list = ed.getElementList(inputUrl);
        return list;
    }
}).flatMap (list -> list.iterator())
.foreach ((String element) -> { 
    // here put code that is in processElementList
 });
```

I've used lambda syntax, you can use anonymous functions of course

Edit: Make sure `Elements` is serializable

Comment: This works thanks. Is there a way but to find out is the code really running in parallel? actually my ed.processElementList( inputUrl, list);

Comment: You will have to provide more code on what is inside of ExtractTrainingData.

Comment: if it works, and you are okay then you can vote-up/accept the question as owner. if you don't have enough previlage then at least pls accept

Comment: You want to parallelize also result of `ed.getElementList(inputUrl)`? Currently it works as one URL -> one ExtractTrainingData is created -> all elements from single `getElementList` is processed in the same thread. If you want to parallelize also processing of element of this list, use `map` instead of `foreach`, return list and do flatMap

Comment: @Derek_M thanks for edit, I wrote it without IDE and that's why there was typo ;) One more thing, result type was wrong, that's why I've edited it again

Comment: @T.Gawęda      

    .flatMap (list -> list.iterator())
    .foreach ((String element) -> { 
    // here put code that is in processElementList
     });      
This did not work for me.. As my processElementList method uses both  line and list..

Comment: @ysg7790 Instead of first map, do flatMap. Create list of tuples (line, elementFromList) and remove next flatMap. I cannot write full code now, if you want I can edit answer at ~ 20:00 UTC